# Как делают передвижение в онлайн играх?

Tags: unity3d, сервер, сеть, разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мое понимание процесса передвижения в
рамках Unity:**

Частота обновлений в FixedUpdate очень мала для отображения плавной картинки, поэтому разумнее передвигать персонажа в Update.

Мы посылаем ввод серверу в одном из вызовов FixedUpdate. Сервер, обрабатывая пришедший ввод, передвигает у себя игрока на 1 условный метр. Но из за разницы частоты обновления сервера и клиента, клиент передвинет своего персонажа на 7 условных метров дальше (это число зависит от качества сети и нагруженности поцессора).

**Суть вопроса**

Где в моих рассуждения допущена ошибка?
Как на самом деле делают передвижение в онлайн играх, ведь у War Thunder и World of Tanks частота обновлений всего-то 20-30 Гц?

Comment: Ошибка в первом же предложении *"Частота обновлений в FixedUpdate очень мала для отображения плавной картинки"*. Частота обновлений в Fixed Updated не должна влиять на частоту и плавность отображения картинки. Кроме того, при получении обновлений с сервера состояние клиента должно обновлять ретроспективно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, на сервере есть FPS (Update() на вашей диаграмме) и tick rate (аналог Fixed Update), который более редкий.

Поправлю некоторые утверждения:

> Сервер, обрабатывая пришедший ввод, передвигает у себя игрока на 1
> условный метр. Но из за разницы частоты обновления сервера и клиента,
> клиент передвинет своего персонажа на 7 условных метров дальше

Это утверждение неверно, т.к. все движения умножаются на время от кадра к кадру. Скажем, время между Update() - 0.25 сек, а между FixedUpdate() - 1 сек.
Если скорость - 1 метр в секунду, то каждый Update() будет двигать персонажа на 1 * 0.25 метров, а каждый FixedUpdate() - на 1 * 1 метров в секунду. За 4 Update() получится то же самое, что и за 1 FixedUpdate().
Но все равно если бы на клиенте движение было в Update(), а на сервере - в FixedUpdate(), были бы небольшие, накапливающиеся расхождения, поэтому читаем дальше.

> Частота обновлений в FixedUpdate очень мала для отображения плавной
> картинки, поэтому разумнее передвигать персонажа в Update.

Эта догадка логична, но работает все не так). Движение реально происходит в FixedUpdate() и на сервере, и на клиенте, но двигаемый объект никак не рисуется на экране. Вместо этого на клиенте есть отдельный "графический объект", который плавно следует за скачущим "реальным" объектом. Вот он обновляется в Update() чаще, создавая иллюзию плавности.

**В одном ответе не поместить все детали синхронизации, надо читать соответствующие статьи, но к сути вопроса:**

Tick Rate 20-30 гц - это очень много, не "всего-то" :)

Да, при 20 гц tick rate может быть задержка на ввод до 50 мс (в среднем в районе 25мс), но это очень незаметно.
Когда, благодаря интерполяции в Update(), про которую я упомянул выше, визуально все выглядит очень плавно, очень сложно заметить 1-50 мс задержку на ввод.

Comment: Игроки Counter-Strike, предпочитающие играть на 128 тикрейте, вряд ли согласятся с последним абзацем

Comment: А ещё, наверное, те же игроки Counter-Strike скажут, что «графический» объект обязан соответствовать «физическому», а сервер должен уметь просчитывать физику с поправкой на интерполяцию — чтобы было меньше проблем вида «да почему не регает блин»

Comment: Что вы имели ввиду, когда говорили, что сервер имеет Update? Я так понимаю это Receiver входящих сообщений? И последний вопрос: как тогда быть с пользовательским вводом? FixedUpdate для этого не очень подходит. А если использовать Update рано или поздно все равно произойдет рассинхрон между "графическим" и "реальным" объектами.(мы можем изменить направление движения где-нибудь между fixed update'ами, а FixedUpdate сработет уже позднее, когда мы прошли расстояние по новой траектории)

Comment: @Diyabya под Update на сервере я имел в виду обычный Update() метод. Про Receiver сообщений не понял.
Про ввод, да, он обрабатывается в FixedUpdate, очень даже подходит.

Делаю игру, у меня, вкратце, вот так выглядит FixedUpdate() движения на клиенте и сервере:
(отправляю отдельным комментарием ниже, тк не помещается текст в комментарий, хоть я его максимально ужал).

Comment: @Diyabya

Клиент FixedUpdate():
1. Reconcile() - берет последнее состояние (позиции, ротации), которое прислал сервер, и применяет его.
2. Move() - применяет все движения, совершенные с момента состояния Reconcile() до момента сейчас (то есть ввод, непроверенный сервером, кешируется на клиенте). Так же Move() отправляет ввод движения текущего FixedUpdate() на сервер.

Comment: @Diyabya Сервер FixedUpdate(): 

1. Move() - применяет ввод движения клиента.
2. Reconcile() - отправляет полученное состояние клиенту для Reconcile().

Ну и поверх этого всего интерполяция на клиенте, как и говорил, и все получается четко. Даже на 10-15гц тик рейте нереально заметить input lag, если это не FPS игра.

P.S. Сорри за форматтинг, стековерфлоу убрал все переносы линий из коммента и стало выглядеть нечитабельно)